# How to store two different values returned from query into list data types to be used later(plpy python)

Tags: python, postgresql, plpy

I need to store two values, "id" and "name" returned from sql query into a variable which I can use later. Can I use list for this purpose. I want to store values from sql at once and then only to refer to the stored value. I was able to do so but with only one value (id), but now I need to store  both id and name together. the purpose is to do string comparision and based on it, its corresponding id is to be assigned.

for example ,first i tried to retrieve data from database by
 rv = plpy.execute (select id,name from aa) 
Now I need to store these two values somewhere in two varaible for example, lets say id in storevalueID and name in storevalueName so later I can do things like, 
if someXname = Replace(storeValueName("hello","")) then 
assign its concerned id to some varaible lile xID = storevalueID,
 I am not sure if we can do this , but i need to do something like this.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question? Write as much of the code as you can, what your output is, then what you really want the output to be.

Comment: I am writing plpy postgresql code;

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me out enough. As I said, if you have a code sample that doesn't work, perhaps we can figure out why it doesn't, or at least have a better idea of what you're trying to do. If not, you'll need to reword your description, because I can't understand it.

Comment: Oops there were some error while i was typing text. I added codes in my question to make it more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely.  But if you were previously storing a list of "id"s:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(id1)  # or however you get your id values
mylist.append(id2)
# ..
```

so mylist is something like [1, 2, 3], then you can simply use tuples to store more than one element that are associated together:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append( (id1, name1) )
mylist.append( (id2, name2) )
# ..
```

Now mylist is something like `[ (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Alice'), (3, 'Carol')]`.  You can perform string comparisons on the second element of each tuple in your list:

```
mylist[0][1] == 'Bob'  # True
mylist[1][2] == 'Alice'  # True
```

*Update*  I just saw the updated question.  In plypy, you should be able to access the variables like this:

```
for row in rv:
    the_id = row['id']
    name = row['name']
```

using the column names.  See [this page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol2/DatabaseAccess.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I Cannot use the last option you mentioned, as I need to store the whole list in global variable and then used it later for string comparision, I was able to do that for one column value for example, SD[id] = list, but here I need to store id and name in SD, something like SD[id, name] = list[id, name], is this possible??

Comment: @newbiePython: You can do this `SD['keyname']` = (id, name). This is almost certainly the wrong way to do things though. The caller of the function should be storing / using the value, not the function itself. Your values will clobbered if the function is called more than once concurrently. I would repost, state you are using pl/python, and most importantly state why and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @newbiePython: It seems like SD is a dictionary?  In which case, you can use tuples as keys to the dictionary: `SD[ (id, name) ] = list( (id, name) )`.  However, I'm not sure why you need to have the key and value be the same -- you might be better off using a list alone: `SD = [];  SD.append( (id, name) ) # for each row`.